# Generate graph from a list of connected components

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, connected-components

###### Setup

Let's assume the following undirected graph:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_edgelist([(0, 3), (0, 1), (2, 5), (0, 3)])
G.add_nodes_from(range(7))
```

[image: graph]

or even adding the (1, 3) edge (it doesn't matter here):

[image]

The connected components are:

```py
list(nx.connected_components(G))
# [{0, 1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4}, {6}]
```

###### Question

Is it possible to generate the graph `G` from the list of connected components directly with `networkx`? Or using a simple method?

The only solution I found so far is to generate the successive edges or all combinations of nodes per group and feed it to [`nx.from_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_edgelist.html), then to add the single nodes with [`add_nodes_from`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from.html):

```py
from itertools import pairwise, chain

l = [{0, 1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4}, {6}]

G = nx.from_edgelist(chain.from_iterable(pairwise(e) for e in l))
G.add_nodes_from(set.union(*l))
```

or for all edges:

```py
from itertools import combinations, chain

l = [{0, 1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4}, {6}]

G = nx.from_edgelist(chain.from_iterable(combinations(e, 2) for e in l))
G.add_nodes_from(set.union(*l))
```

Comment: The question is which edges you want to assume between the nodes in the connected components. Simple choices would be either fully connected (as you did) or a simple line. As long as each node has at least one edge - or in other words as long as the connected component consists of at least 2 nodes - you don't need to additionally add the nodes via add_nodes_from.

Comment: @Sparky05 the exact edges do not really matter here (ideally a solution for both: "first from list order" and "all connected" would be nice). Regarding adding the existing nodes, I know it's not required I just added all for simplicity ;)

Comment: Don't use `permutations`. Use `combinations`. There are exactly twice as many elements in `permutations(cc, 2)` as in `combinations(cc, 2)`, and those are all redundant elements if G is a simple undirected graph.

Comment: *"of course combinations would give the first graph and permutations the second one."* I don't understand. Why would `combinations` and `permutations` give different graphs? My point is precisely that they would give the exact same graph, but `combinations` is more efficient.

Comment: @mozway I just ran the two code snippets from your update. The two graphs have the exact same list of edges.

Comment: Also note that `G = nx.from_edgelist(chain.from_iterable(list(combinations(e, 2)) for e in l))` is equivalent to `G = nx.from_edgelist(chain(combinations(cc, 2) for cc in l))`. You don't need to build a `list( )` then use `.from_iterable`.

Comment: @Stef I simplified the question to focus on my real question. This was just an example here. What I **really** care about is to know if `networkx` can do this natively. (NB. you were right on the edgelist btw, I hadn't checked)

Comment: Also note that if you don't care about collecting all edges, just about collecting enough edges to get the same connected components, then you only need one path per connected component. This can be obtained with `pairwise`: `from itertools import pairwise; G = nx.from_edgelist(pairwise(cc) for cc in l)`. Then you have a number of edges which is linear instead of quadratic.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant (`pairwise`/`combination` not `combinations`/`permutations`), but again, not the question ;)

Comment: @Stef I updated the question, thanks for your correction (I had brainfreeze when writing it), Now I hope to get a `networkx` answer

Comment: Okay, how about `G = nx.union_all(nx.path_graph(cc) for cc in l)` (equivalent to using pairwise) or `G = nx.union_all(nx.complete_graph(cc) for cc in l)` (equivalent to using combinations)

Comment: @Stef that's quite nice! (especially using `map`). Thanks! (don't hesitate if you want to post as answer). Would you know an equivalent for all combinations of edges?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An alternative to `itertools.pairwise` is [`networkx.path_graph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.classic.path_graph.html).

An alternative to `itertools.combinations` is [`networkx.complete_graph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.classic.complete_graph.html).

These two networkx functions return a new graph, not a list of edges, so you can combine them with [`networkx.compose_all`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.all.compose_all.html).

Note also [`union_all`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.all.union_all.html) and [`disjoint_union_all`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.all.disjoint_union_all.html#networkx.algorithms.operators.all.disjoint_union_all) as alternatives to `compose_all`.

```py
import networkx as nx

l = [{0, 1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4}, {6}]

G = nx.compose_all(map(nx.path_graph, l))

H = nx.compose_all(map(nx.complete_graph, l))

print(G.nodes, G.edges)
# [0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6] [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 5)]

print(H.nodes, H.edges)
# [0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6] [(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 5)]
```

I haven't actually run benchmarks, but I suspect creating several graphs and composing them might be slower than creating lists of edges and chaining them to create only one graph.

Comment: Small feedback. The `itertools` version seem much faster (~10-20x), which is probably expected. I also realized it would fail on such input `l = [{0, 1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4}, {6, 0}]` (which is not strictly a list of connected components), but I found that [`compose_all`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.all.compose_all.html) would work well in this case. Very nice tools, I'm learning to love it ;)