# How to find related rows based on column value similarity with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, networkx, graph-theory

Given a random dataset, I need to find rows related to the first row.

```
|Row|Foo|Bar|Baz|Qux|
|---|---|---|---|---|
| 0 | A |A |A | A |
| 1 | B | B | B | B |
| 2 | C | C | C |D|
| 3 | D |A | D |D|
```

I should get the related rows which are 0, 2, and 3 because `0['Bar'] == 3['Bar']` and `3['Qux'] == 2['Qux']`.

I can just iterate over the columns to get the similarities but that would be slow and inefficient and I would also need to iterate again if there are new similarities.

I hope someone can point me to the right direction like which `pandas` concept should I be looking at or which functions can help me solve this problem of retrieving intersecting data. Do I even need to use `pandas`?

Edit:

Providing the solution as suggested by @goodside. This solution will loop until there are no more new matched index found.

```
table = [
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
['C', 'C', 'C', 'D'],
['D', 'A', 'D', 'D']
]

comparators = [0]

while True:
  for idx_row, row in enumerate(table):
    if idx_row in comparators:
      continue

    for idx_col, cell in enumerate(row):
      for comparator in comparators:
        if cell == table[comparator][idx_col]:
          comparators.append(idx_row)
          break
      else:
        continue
      break
    else:
      continue
    break
  else:
    break

for item in comparators:
  print(table[item])
```

Comment: How do you imagine the output looking?

Comment: Can you add more context on exactly what problem you’re trying to solve? You seem to be after a specific definition of relatedness — rows that share one or more elements with a given row, correct? Can you give an example of how the problem would be solved using loops for clarity, even if that solution would be slow? Also consider removing the emojis from your example table as they break formatting and make the question less clear.

Comment: @Chris the output may return the related rows or just the row number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a graph problem. You can use `networkx`:

```
# get the list of connected nodes per column
def get_edges(s):
    return df['Row'].groupby(s).agg(frozenset)

edges = set(df.apply(get_edges).stack())
edges = list(map(set, edges))
# [{2}, {2, 3}, {0, 3}, {3}, {1}, {0}]

from itertools import pairwise, chain
# pairwise is python ≥ 3.10, see the doc for a recipe for older versions

# create the graph
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_edgelist(chain.from_iterable(pairwise(e) for e in edges))
G.add_nodes_from(set.union(*edges))

# get the connected components
list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

Output: `[{0, 2, 3}, {1}]`

*NB. You can read more on the logic to create the graph in [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71049155/generate-graph-from-a-list-of-connected-components).*

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Row': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'Foo': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'Bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
                   'Baz': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'Qux': ['A', 'B', 'D', 'D']})
```

Comment: I tested this approach and it's definitely faster than the solution I had.