# Creating hierarchy using 4 columns in dataframe - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx

Dataframe is below

```
    ID        ParentID   Filter Text
0  98           97       NULL   AA
1  99            98      NULL   BB
2  100           99      NULL   CC
3  107           100     1      DD
4  9999        1231     NULL   EE
5  10000        1334    NULL    FF
6  10001        850     2       GG
7   850          230    NULL    HH
8   230          121    NULL    II
9   121          96     NULL    JJ
10 96            0      NULL    KK
11 97            0      NULL    LL
```

I need to add an additional column hierarchy like this:

```
    ID        ParentID   Filter Text   Hierarchy
0  98           97       NULL   AA
1  99            98      NULL   BB
2  100           99      NULL   CC
3  107           100     1      DD      DD/CC/BB/AA/LL
4  9999        1231     NULL   EE
5  10000        1334    NULL    FF
6  10001        850     2       GG      GG/HH/II/JJ/KK
7   850          230    NULL    HH
8   230          121    NULL    II
9   121          96     NULL    JJ
10 96            0      NULL    KK
11 97            0      NULL    LL
```

The rules I am looking at are below:

1. Only populate hierarchy column for rows which have filter value populated, the rest of the rows don't need hierarchy done.
2. When a row is found having filter value not null, lookup its parentID, then search this parentid in ID column. When found reclusively keep going up till, parent id is 0.
3. Trying to do this with itertools but the looping is taking too long as the original dataset is huge

4)Recordset size is ~ 200k

The below solution provided kindly by mozway seems to work but for a recorset of 200k records, it takes a lot of time. Is there a tweak that can be done to this to get to the solution faster ?

Comment: Do you have duplicated values in ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution involving one pass of dfs for each root node.
The worst time complexity is `O(V + FV)` where `V` is the number of columns and `F` is
the number of columns to populate hierarchy for.
This might be faster than other solutions as it exploits the fact that the
given graph is a tree and hence there is only one path from root to any node.

```py
# this is a recursive dfs code with additional logic to store the hierarchy
# of interesting nodes
def dfs(graph, stack, interesting, hierarchy):
    node = stack[-1]
    for child in graph[node]:
        stack.append(child)
        if child in interesting:
            hierarchy[child] = stack[:]
        dfs(graph, stack, interesting, hierarchy)
    stack.pop()


# make 'ID' the index
df = df.set_index("ID")

# find the roots
roots = df[df["ParentID"] == 0].index
# interesting nodes to find the hierarchy for
interesting = set(df[df["Filter"].notna()].index)
# dict to store the id -> hierarchy mapping
hierarchy = {}

# build a directed graph in adjacency list of parent -> children
graph = defaultdict(list)
for node, parent in zip(df.index, df["ParentID"]):
    graph[parent].append(node)

# run dfs on each root
for root in roots:
    stack = [root]
    dfs(graph, stack, interesting, hierarchy)

# populate the hierarchy column
df["Hierarchy"] = ""
for node, path in hierarchy.items():
    df.loc[node, "Hierarchy"] = "/".join(df.loc[path, "Text"])

# make 'ID' a column again
df = df.reset_index()

# now we're done!
print(df)
```

Full code is in https://pastebin.com/6MFaqZQw.

Comment: This is extremely fast, the only thing I can see is that the root element appears at the last of the hierarchy instead of the first

Comment: For creating hierarchy I have updated the code to use path.reverse() and I get what I am afte.

Comment: @misguided I changed the line 8 into `hierarchy[child] = stack[:]`. (I was following the example provided on your question.)

Answer (score 3):

This is a graph problem, which you can easily solve with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org).

- create a directed graph with [`nx.from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html)
- find the roots with a list comprehension and [`in_degree`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.in_degree.html)
- get the paths between the selected nodes and the roots using [`all_simple_paths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html) and a mapping Series
- assign to you DataFrame

```
import networkx as nx

m = df['Filter'].notna()
nodes = df.loc[m, 'ID']

mapper = df[m].set_index('ID')['Text']

# create graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='ParentID', target='ID',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# find roots
roots = {n for n, deg in G.in_degree() if deg==0}
# {1231, 1334, 0}

# retrieve hierarchy
df.loc[m, 'Hierarchy'] = [
    ';'.join(['/'.join([mapper.get(x) for x in p[:0:-1]])
                        for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, r, n)])
    for n in nodes for r in roots
    for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, r, n)
]
```

*Note that there could be several hierarchies if the graph is branched. In this case, this would return all of them separated by `;`.*

Output:

```
       ID  ParentID  Filter Text       Hierarchy
0      98        97     NaN   AA             NaN
1      99        98     NaN   BB             NaN
2     100        99     NaN   CC             NaN
3     107       100     1.0   DD  DD/CC/BB/AA/LL
4    9999      1231     NaN   EE             NaN
5   10000      1334     NaN   FF             NaN
6   10001       850     2.0   GG  GG/HH/II/JJ/KK
7     850       230     NaN   HH             NaN
8     230       121     NaN   II             NaN
9     121        96     NaN   JJ             NaN
10     96         0     NaN   KK             NaN
11     97         0     NaN   LL             NaN
```

Graph:

[image: graph hierarchy]

##### potential optimization

If the dataset is huge, a potential optimization might be to only iterate over the roots that are part of the connected components. You'd have to try in the real dataset if this improves performance.

```
import networkx as nx

m = df['Filter'].notna()
nodes = df.loc[m, 'ID']

mapper = df[m].set_index('ID')['Text']

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='ParentID', target='ID', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

roots = {n for n, deg in G.in_degree() if deg==0}
# {1231, 1334, 0}

roots_dict = {n: s&roots for s in nx.weakly_connected_components(G) for n in s}

df.loc[m, 'Hierarchy'] = [
    ';'.join(['/'.join([mapper.get(x) for x in p[:0:-1]])
                        for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, r, n)])
    for n in nodes for r in roots_dict[n]
    for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, r, n)
]
```

Comment: getting  'AttributeError: module 'mapper' has no attribute 'get'' error

Comment: Sorry I forgot to provide this variable, this is not a module but a series (`mapper = df[m].set_index('ID')['Text']`). See update.

Comment: ';'.join(['/'.join([mapper.get(x) for x in p[:0:-1]])
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found

Comment: Then you have non text in the "Text" column, change to `';'.join(['/'.join([str(mapper.get(x)) for x in p[:0:-1]])`

Comment: How much time do you expect this to run for 200k records? :)

Comment: I don't know, **you** tell me ;)

Comment: ha ha fair enough, super excited that this is working, just waiting for the results to come out

Comment: If you want to compare timing with that of a pure python loop, keep it mind that networkx is not necessarily faster than a pure python loop. It surely helps when you want to achieve complex things as it has built-in graph theory algorithms, however if the logic is simple and linear, python might be more efficient. See for instance [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71049155/generate-graph-from-a-list-of-connected-components) in which the pure python approach was eventually faster.

Comment: No output still, sure does take a lot of time :) Will leave this overnight and check results in the morning tomorrow

Comment: Hmmm doesn't look good, it has been 16 hours still no result unfortunately. :(

Comment: @misguided can you provide a reproducible large dataset? My code tries to retrieve all hierarchies, but you might want to stop to the first ones. How branched is your dataset?

Comment: No reliable way to provide the dataset without showing proprietary information :(

Comment: @misguided can't you `factorize` the IDs? The structure of the graph would help, the actual IDs don't matter. Worse thing, can you show a plot of the graph shape (anonymized IDs would be better)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try dictionaries. Not sure, but let's see.
Creating a test dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID': [98, 99, 100, 107, 9999, 10000, 10001, 850, 230, 121, 96, 97],
    'ParentID': [97, 98, 99, 100, 1231, 1334, 850, 230, 121, 96, 0, 0],
    'Filter Text': [None, None, None, '1', None, None, '2', None, None, None, None, None],
    'Text': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF', 'GG', 'HH', 'II', 'JJ', 'KK', 'LL']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Initialize where you will keep your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Hierarchy'] = ""

parent_child_dict = {}
```

The main logic to play with dictionaries

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    current_id = row['ID']
    parent_id = row['ParentID']
    
    parent_child_dict[current_id] = parent_id

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    hierarchy = []
    current_id = row['ID']
    
    while current_id != 0:
        parent_id = parent_child_dict.get(current_id)
        
        if parent_id is None:
            break
        
        parent_row = df.loc[df['ID'] == parent_id]
        
        if parent_row.empty:
            break
        
        parent_text = parent_row['Text'].values[0]
        hierarchy.insert(0, parent_text)
        current_id = parent_id
    
    hierarchy.append(row['Text'])
    
    df.at[index, 'Hierarchy'] = '/'.join(hierarchy)
print(df)
```